# Undefined index... but it says it's defined in the debugger

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, scope

(EDIT: I solved my issue! Though I still don't understand the situation I see in the debugger. See my answer for more details)

(TL;DR: index is always undefined when used with a certain array. Doubt that would be enough info, but maybe for someone who's experienced this before.)

So basically, I'm using an array in javascript, and I started noticing some odd behaviour, so I went to the debugger, and I found that a defined variable representing the index was being treated as undefined. It's ONLY the case with this specific array, and it's index. I don't get errors saying that it's undefined, but when I look in the debugger, it says it's undefined when I hover over the variable in the array call (but it's defined if I hover over it anywhere before the array call), and I'm getting bugs that make it clear that the array is not being used properly. It makes absolutely no sense to me, but maybe someone's encountered a similar issue.

Take this example of code, It's drawing a tilemap layer for my MapRenderer class. The culprit here is "this.Map.layers". When I go into this function in the debugger, layerIndex is defined if I hover over the function parameter, but if I hover over it on the array call, it says it's undefined, and the whole logic breaks.

```
DrawLayer(ctx, camPos, layerIndex)
{
    // Get the map/tile position based on the camera position, to decide which tile to start drawing.
    var mapCamPos = new Point(Math.floor(camPos.x/TILESIZE),
                              Math.floor(camPos.y/TILESIZE));
    // Get the max tile position based on camera position, to decide where to stop drawing.
    var camPosLimit = new Point(Math.ceil(this.DrawSize.x/TILESIZE)+mapCamPos.x,
                                Math.ceil(this.DrawSize.y/TILESIZE)+mapCamPos.y);

    // loop through all tiles we need to draw using rows and columns.
    for(var row=mapCamPos.y;row<this.Map.layers[layerIndex].height&&row<=camPosLimit.y;row++)
    {
        for(var col=mapCamPos.x;col<this.Map.layers[layerIndex].width&&col<=camPosLimit.x;col++)
        {
            var currentTileID = this.GetTileID(layerIndex, row, col);
            if (currentTileID >= 0 && !isNaN(currentTileID))
            {
                var drawPos = new Point(((col*TILESIZE)-camPos.x), ((row*TILESIZE)-camPos.y));
                this.Spritesheet.PlayFrame(currentTileID);
                this.Spritesheet.Draw(ctx, drawPos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is happening in many instances of my code wherever I'm using that array. I want to add how this started, because all of this logic was working previously. I had my tilemap working with multiple csv files, which I loaded as 2d arrays into an array. Today, I decided to switch it all to use one json file, as it is simply cleaner (one file rather than one csv per map layer), and I can add extra properties and stuff in the future rather than just having the tileIDs. So, in the above example, this.Map gets initialized through an ajax call(using jquery) to read the json file, before DrawLayer ever gets called. Still, I don't see why this would cause this. Doing "mapRenderer.Map.layers" in the console tells me that it's a normal array, and when I try calling it normally from the console, it works fine. I'm so confused at this issue. I had literally the same function before and it worked, just that my array has changed a bit(it used to be just "this.Layers", instead of "this.Map.layers"), but it's still a normal array... I don't see why it would behave so differently just because it was generated via json...

Any help or explanations would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you hover over the second `layerIndex`, are you sure it doesn't think you're hovering over `this.Map.layers[layerIndex]`?

Comment: Which browser is this?

Comment: Is this ajax call asynchronous? If so, where is the `DrawLayer` function being called from? After the ajax call, or inside its success handler? Because if it's after then I'd expect that the result from the ajax call wouldn't have arrived yet, so `this.Map.layers` wouldn't yet contain the data.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Firefox. It's definitely just looking at layerIndex, not the whole thing. Yes it's asynchronous, and this.Map.layers is definitely populated before DrawLayers is called. So this is a game (obviously), and before the main menu even loads, this.Map gets assigned in the success handler for the ajax call, and only after the ajax call (the 'completed' handler) does the main menu show up, and even after that, a button needs to be clicked to start the game and THEN the DrawLayer function gets called.

Comment: @DavidKnipe alright, well I managed to fix the issues I had. I still don't understand the situation I see in the debugger though, I suppose it's a firefox bug, or just something I don't understand about the way it's displaying variables. My main issue was simple logic...: I'm using the "Tiled" map editor, and when you export that to CSV, the tile IDs are zero-based, meaning empty tiles are -1. When you export to json, they aren't zero-based, meaning empty tiles are 0, and this was the root of many issues. But like I said I still don't get that whole undefined index in the debugger. Oh well.

Comment: Unrelated: remember that `var` has function scope. To avoid any misunderstandings, move your variable declarations (`var whatever`) to the top of your function.

Comment: @jcaron I understand that... But moving all my declarations to the top seems like a style preference, I don't know how I feel about it... I find it easier to follow this way because you can see where the variables start being used. If I read code with the empty declarations at the top, I'd be wondering why they were declared there and I would spend a bit more time paying attention to where those variables are being used. Like this, the var keyword tells me the variable starts being used at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand the situation I see in the debugger, maybe it's a firefox bug, or feature I don't understand. But I managed to fix my issue. It was a basic logic bug: I'm using the "Tiled" map editor, and when you export those maps to CSVs, the tile IDs are zero-based, meaning empty tiles are -1. When you export to json, they aren't zero-based, meaning empty tiles are 0, which I failed to notice, and this was the root of all my current issues. If anyone can explain why the firefox debugger might say defined variables are "undefined" when you hover over them, that would still be good to know.